# How to print a value using json several levels above?

Tags: json, jq

Given a json such as:

```
{
"clusters": [
  {
      "domain": "crap1",
      "name": "BB1",
      "nodes": [
        {
            "gpu": null,
            "node": "bb1-1",
            "role": "worker"
        },
        {
            "gpu": {
                "P40": 2
            },
            "node": "bb1-2",
            "role": "master"
        }
   ],
   "site": "B-place",
   "hardware": "prod-2",
   "timezone": "US/Eastern",
   "type": "CCE",
   "subtype": null
  }
  ]
}
```

where there are actually many more clusters, I want to see if I can parse the json searching for node bb1-2, for example, and print out the cluster name it belongs to BB1?
I know I can search for that node with:

```
.clusters[] | .nodes[] | select(.node == "bb1-2")
```

but can't figure out how to code it to print out a value at a higher level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
.clusters[] |  select(.nodes[].node == "bb1-2").name
```

Try it:
[JQ play](https://jqplay.org/s/Rp2KzSe1we)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other approaches, a very general way to hold on to higher level context is to bind it to a variable.

```
jq '
    .clusters[] |
    . as $cluster |
    .nodes[] |
    select(.node == "bb1-2") |
    {cluster_name:$cluster.name, node:.}
'
```

```
{
  "cluster_name": "BB1",
  "node": {
    "gpu": {
      "P40": 2
    },
    "node": "bb1-2",
    "role": "master"
  }
}
```

This makes sure you know *both* the cluster *and* the matching node itself, and avoids the confusion that arises if your `select` condition matches the same cluster more than once.